# Deserialize a generic object in ServiceStack.Text

Tags: servicestack-text

I tried to find a solution for deserializing an anonymous object from JSON to a structure resembling the original JSON structure in ServiceStack.Text, but I did not find any acceptable solution. While I do understand that the deserializer does not have a clue about how to deserialize a generic object, I am ready to indicate it some rules like:

- use for any generic object a Dictionary<string, object> or ExpandoObject, whichever the deserializer likes best
- use for any list a List<object>

I tried to deserialize to a Dictionary<string, object>, but the entries are all strings, no matter if I have complex object inside or not, or even lists. The next try was with ExpandoObject, which was a little better, recognizing the lists as List<object>, but the objects inside are all strings. I assumed that for the scenario with the two rules indicated above it should be a simple configuration issue, but I did not find any possibility.

Does anyone have a clue in solving this puzzle? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the following settings do the trick:

```
JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true;
JsConfig.TryToParsePrimitiveTypeValues = false; // otherwise, for untyped jsons, any string value which can't be converted to primitive types will return null.

var dictionary = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(json, typeof(object));
```

Another option would be the `DynamicJson` class provided by ServiceStack.Text, but the implementation does not preserve the original names from the JSON.

For an alternative implementation, check the JsonExpando class in Kephas Framework (https://github.com/quartz-software/kephas/blob/master/src/Kephas.Serialization.ServiceStack.Text/JsonExpando.cs). Important: use the above settings in `JsonConfig`.